# Is there a way to list all members in a specific role?

Tags: discord.js

I was wondering if it is possible to list every member within a specific role.
If possible to make it so I can search for every role without changing the code, and changing roleid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple ways to get a list of every [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) that has a specific [Role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role).

You can use `.members` [Role property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) to get a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

Example :

```js
// Getting a Collection of all GuildMember that have the role stored in "myRole" var.
let myRole = client.guilds.resolve("651196009896214543").roles.cache.get("651197514506305555");
let members = myRole.members
```

Or you can filter all [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) of a [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) like that :

```js
let members = client.guilds.resolve("651196009896214543").members.cache;
members = members.filter(guildMember => guildMember.roles.cache.has("651197514506305555"));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping mate, exactly what i needed